# How to display HTML form input elements (Bootstrap's class "form-group" ) inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's form-group and form-control classes to create a simple HTML from. Please refer the screenshots. I tried setting the display property of form-control class to inline, but the html elements are not getting displayed inline. PFB my code snippet.

```
  <div id="user_search" class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
        <label for="search_id" class="label_font">Search Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_id" placeholder="Movie Title, TV Show title..." size="40">
    <label for="genre_id" >Genre</label>
    <select  id="genre_id">
        <option></option>
        <option>Action</option>
        <option>Adventure</option>
        <option>Animation</option>
        <option>Biography</option>
        <option>Comedy</option>
        <option>Crime</option>
        <option>Documentary</option>
        <option>Drama</option>
        <option>Family</option>
        <option>Fantasy</option>
        <option>Film-Noir</option>
        <option>Game-Show</option>
        <option>History</option>
        <option>Horror</option>
        <option>Music</option>
        <option>Musical</option>
        <option>Mystery</option>
        <option>News</option>
        <option>Reality-TV</option>
        <option>Romance</option>
        <option>Sci-Fi</option>
        <option>Sport</option>
        <option>Talk-Show</option>
        <option>Thriller</option>
        <option>War</option>
        <option>Western</option>
    </select>
    <label for="type_id" >Title Type</label>
    <select id="type_id">
        <option></option>
        <option>Movie</option>
        <option>TV Show</option>
    </select>
    <label for="year_id" >Year</label>
    <input type="number"  width="10" min="1900" max="2025" step="1" value="2016" id="year_id">
    <button type="button"  id="search_Title">Search Title</button>

</div>
```

CSS file

`.form-control{
    display:inline;}`

I also tried  display:inline!important. But couldn't see any difference. I want all the form to be displayed in a single line using bootstrap's form-group and form-control classes[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use the `form-inline` class ... as per [Bootstrap documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline-forms). Basically wrap the div with another which has the 'form-inline' class and you should be good. No need for your `display:inline;` additional css.